# DBResourceFactory issue on production (after publishing)

Tags: asp.net, .net, resources, globalization, resx

I have a DBResourceFactory in my ASP.net project and the newly added resources (in the databsae) work fine on localhost but they dont work on production.if i add them to files(resx) they start working fine. but dont work through database. I have reset the IIS too.

Comment: what is your database error?

Comment: there is no database error

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a db permission problem. You need to grant permission for the Application Pool identity that IIS is using for your website project to access the production database. You can do this in Sql Server Management Studio (if you are using Sql Server that is)

Comment: all other data from db is loading correctly, and there is no exception

Comment: I've not used DbResourceFactory. Does it depend on its own ConnectionString (which might differ from the one used by the rest of your data services)